# How to deserialize data once for use many times and multiple threads on a python server?

Tags: python, flask, global

Consider a large binary file `large_file.pkl` that deserializes to an object which is needed by `some_function.py`. Naively, we can deserialize `large_file.pkl` every time `some_function.py` runs (in my case, each time a request is made to the flask server), but this would be slow and prevents us from running `some_function.py` in multiple threads at once.  Is there a pythonic way to deserialize `large_file.pkl` once, store that object instance in memory and use as needed in each thread that `some_function.py` runs?

I have tried to create a file `unpickler.py` that essentially does this:

```
from pickle import load
def create_global_large_object():
    global large_object
    with open('large_file.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        large_object = pickle.load(f)
```

Then, according to the way I believe `global` works, I do the following in `some_function.py`:

```
def run():
    ...
    large_object.cool_method()
    ...
```

However, when I run the following test:

```
from unpickler import create_global_large_object
from some_function import run
def test_idea():
    create_global_large_object()
    run()
```

I get a `NameError: name 'large_object' is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

`large_object` is a global in the unpickler module, so to access it from another module you need to `import unpickler`, and call it like this:

```
unpickler.large_object.cool_method()
```

Comment: `large_object` is not defined in `unpickler.py` unless we explicitly call `create_global_lage_object()`, and if some_function.run() does `unpickler.create_global_lage_object()`, it defeats the purpose of this exercise because, in doing so, we will deserialize `large_file.pkl`